# C# Memory Usage Problem

Tags: c#, .net

I have an method and it converts pdf text into a list. After the process the memory usage increase too much. For example a 1000 page pdf use 300mb memory and i can't free it. I have readed some LOH articles but have not find a solution.

```
 public List<string> GetTextFromPdf()
    {
        if (_pdfDoc.Pages == null) return null;
        List<string> ocrList = new List<string>();

        foreach (var words in _pdfDoc.Pages.Select(s => s.Value.WordList))
        {
            ocrList.AddRange(words.Select(word => word.Word).Select(input => Regex.Replace(input, @"[\W]", "")));
        }

        GC.Collect();
        return ocrList;
    }
```

Comment: Don't re-parse the regex every time - use a shared `Regex` instance

Comment: This is probably an issue with your PDF library

Comment: Is your `_pdfDoc` object disposable?

Comment: the _pdfDoc wrapper class is disposable

Comment: @SLaks what do you mean don't parse the regex every time. Can you give me an example

Comment: How do you measure memory and how big are the PDFs ?

Comment: @Henk Holterman The pdf file is 100mb. After opening the pdf the mem increase only 10mb. The problem is at the parse process. I watch mem usage from Process Explorer.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/06/25/optimizing-regular-expression-performance-part-i-working-with-the-regex-class-and-regex-objects.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is about normal for a 100 megabyte .pdf.  You load the entire thing in memory, that takes double the amount of memory since a character in .NET takes 2 bytes.  You will also create a bunch of garbage in the large object heap for the list.  Add the typical .NET runtime overhead and 300 megabytes is not an unexpected result.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247773/is-it-worthwhile-to-initialize-the-collection-size-of-a-listt-if-its-size-reas/2248188#2248188) for details on how using the List<>.Capacity property can help reduce the LOH demands.

Comment: I'm curious about why you think PDFs aren't already in Unicode?

Comment: @Eric - PDF has been around too long to benefit from Unicode standardization.  It has the typical 8-bit encoding zoo, "WinAnsi" is one of them.

Comment: i cleared the list and set capacity to 0 but the memory usage is still same

Comment: Yes, it is rare for the Windows memory manager to release virtual memory.  The odds that the released memory exactly matches a memory mapping is very low.  Not a problem, it is virtual.  Minimize your main window to make yourself feel better.  The linked answer tried to explain how to reduce LOH usage by not allocating it in the first place.

Comment: @Orhan : It's not (just) about clearing the list but about allocating it wisely. Like `ocrList = new List<string>(_pdfDoc.Pages.Count * OverEstimateWordsPerPage);`

Answer (score 0):

Check if your pdf loader is referenced somewhere - so it can not be disposed.

Comment: The problem is after adding the words to my ocrList. When i call _pdfDoc.Dispose() the app crashes. Because the pdf is still inside a viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Is your pdf library COM based? You may need to call Marshall.releasecomobject on some of your references when you have finished with them.