# C# managed memory leak

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have a simple class :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MyClass c1, c2, c3;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        c1 = new MyClass();
        c2 = new MyClass();
        c3 = new MyClass();
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        c1 = null;
        c2 = null;
        c3 = null;
        GC.Collect();
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    String[] s;
    public MyClass()
    {
        s= new String[1000000];
    }

}
```

When I click button1, The managed memory (Bytes in all heaps counter, perfmon) is growing up (as expected). But when I click button2, I expect that managed memory should be released. But it also grow up !! And only after second button2 click, the memory released.
What is an explanation for this behavior??

And why, when application just started, the "Bytes in all heaps counter" is 0?
I think it should be more than 0 .There are some objects already allocated on managed heap. MainWindow for example..
Thank you, all

Comment: Not 100% sure, but large objects tend to live in a space in memory which is not garbage collected frequently. Also, `GC.Collect()` does not trigger garbage collection, but rather indicates the garbage collector that it should run sooner. Maybe others can comment on this.

Comment: Try inheriting MyClass as IDisposable and call c1.Dispose() after you finish using. By the way, explicitly calling Garbage collector isn't a very good practice though

Comment: @User2012384 I'm not sure`IDisposable` would be useful in this case

Comment: @Micky Just now took a research and found out there's a way to clear the array that's finished using http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-clear-collections, OP can Try clearing the array in the "Dispose" method.

Comment: @User2012384 Interesting. Agreed and thanks!

Comment: You just found out that perfmon is not the right (accurate)  way to monitor memory. There is no leak here.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `GC.Collect`, no memory will be freed. The object without a root will only stored in a queue to be freed. Read some thing about: [GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.gc.waitforpendingfinalizers(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also notice, that objects with the size of more than `~82MB`, will automatically stored in `gen2`, so they will not be collected automatically as far as i know.

There is also a heap for large objects, called: *Large Object Heap (LOH)*. For more information take a look at: [Why Large Object Heap and why do we care?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8953503/2630261)

Hope this informations helps.

Comment: You're mixing the LOH with gen2 here.