# ReadOuterXml is throwing OutOfMemoryException reading part of large (1 GB) XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I am working on a large XML file and while running the application, `XmlTextReader.ReadOuterXml()` method is throwing memory exception.

Lines of codes are like,

```
XmlTextReader xr = null;
try
{
    xr = new XmlTextReader(fileName);
    while (xr.Read() && success)
    {
        if (xr.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) 
            continue;
        switch (xr.Name)
        {
            case "A":
                var xml = xr.ReadOuterXml();
                var n = GetDetails(xml);
                break;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Using:

```
private int GetDetails (string xml)
{

    var rootNode = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    var xnodes = rootNode.XPathSelectElements("//A/B").ToList();
    //Then  working on list of nodes

}
```

Now while loading the XML files, the application throwing exception on the `xr.ReadOuterXml()` line.  What can be done to avoid this?  **The size of XML is almost 1 GB.**

Comment: What size of XML file are we talking about here?

Comment: Simply size of loaded xml is too big. You can consider using iterator and yield result of `GetDetails` which keep memory low.

Comment: Hi @Flater, the size of XML is almost 1 GB

Comment: Hi @Fabio, Yes I can use iterators, but that would affect the performance I believe

Comment: Programming is always tradeoffs between speed/performance and memory size. You need to choose one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason you are getting a `OutOfMemoryException` in `ReadOuterXml()` is that you are trying to read in a substantial portion of the 1 GB XML document into a string, and are hitting the [Maximum string length in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/140468).

**So, don't do that.**  Instead load directly from the `XmlReader` using [`XDocument.Load()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356384(v=vs.110).aspx) with [`XmlReader.ReadSubtree()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(fileName))
{
    while (xr.Read() && success)
    {
        if (xr.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element)
            continue;
        switch (xr.Name)
        {
            case "A":
                {
                    // ReadSubtree() positions the reader at the EndElement of the element read, so the 
                    // next call to Read() moves to the next node.
                    using (var subReader = xr.ReadSubtree())
                    {
                        var doc = XDocument.Load(subReader);
                        GetDetails(doc);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And then in `GetDetails()` do:

```
private int GetDetails(XDocument rootDocument)
{
    var xnodes = rootDocument.XPathSelectElements("//A/B").ToList();
    //Then  working on list of nodes
    return xnodes.Count;
}
```

Not only will this use less memory, it will also be more performant.  [`ReadOuterXml()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReader.cs,2e70466b502f4206,references) uses a temporary `XmlWriter` to copy the XML in the input stream to an output `StringWriter` (which you then parse a second time).  This version of the algorithm completely skips this extra work.  It also avoids creating strings large enough to go on the [large object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8951836) which can cause additional performance issues.

**If this is still using too much memory** you will need to implement [SAX-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) parsing for your XML where you only load one element `<B>` at a time.  First, introduce the following extension method:

```
public static partial class XmlReaderExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<XElement> WalkXmlElements(this XmlReader xmlReader, Predicate<Stack<XName>> filter)
    {
        Stack<XName> names = new Stack<XName>();

        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                names.Push(XName.Get(xmlReader.LocalName, xmlReader.NamespaceURI));
                if (filter(names))
                {
                    using (var subReader = xmlReader.ReadSubtree())
                    {
                        yield return XElement.Load(subReader);
                    }
                }
            }

            if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xmlReader.IsEmptyElement)
                || xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            {
                names.Pop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, use it as follows:

```
using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(fileName))
{
    Predicate<Stack<XName>> filter =
        (stack) => stack.Peek().LocalName == "B" && stack.Count > 1 && stack.ElementAt(1).LocalName == "A";
    foreach (var element in xr.WalkXmlElements(filter))
    {
        //Then working on the specific node.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dbc... This really helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(fileName))
{   
    XmlDocument oXml = new XmlDocument();
    while (reader.Read())
        {                  
            oXml.Load(reader);                    
        }
}
```

For me above code resolved the issue when we return it to XmlDocument through XmlDocument Load method

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is `command`? How are you reading in the file? You need to be detailed when posting code in your solution.

Comment: @ConnorLow  I have updated code with file reader , I was getting the 'System.OutOfMemoryException'  while getting the data from database  therefore added with SQL connection with code but some how it was not saved properly