# Out Of Memory when loading large XML files

Tags: c#, xml, file, out-of-memory

I want to read records from  XML files and save the data to another file or database. The data I am interested in is actually very small but I often run into an "out of memory" exception.
The problem I see is the XML files because some are very large (several gigabytes) and they contain countless records. I don't need all these records at the same time. Whenever I have read a certain number, I save them and discard my read data.

The code to load this data looks like this for me:

```
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(bs))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(reader))
                {
                    while (xr.Read())
                    {
                        switch (xr.NodeType)
                        {
                            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                                if (xr.LocalName == "Record")
                                {
                                    string xml = xr.ReadOuterXml();
                                    // Parse XML, Put data into list, save list and clear list
```

It works fine on smaller files but maybe it is not the best practice for reading very big files.

All suggestions will be gratefully received.

Comment: Why are you using `BufferedStream` it seems unnecessary? Also why create the `XmlReader` *inside* the loop, it could be done outside? Also what are you doing with the results, we can't see the rest of your code apart from `// Parse XML, Put data into list, save list and clear list`

Comment: What is causing the out of memory? Is a single `Record` so huge that it doesn't fit into a string where you use `string xml = xr.ReadOuterXml();`? Or what happens in `// Parse XML, Put data into list, save list and clear list`? In general, the need to do `string xml = xr.ReadOuterXml();` surprises me, I would expect to see the use of e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfrom?view=net-6.0

Comment: See my solution at following which uses a combination of XML Reader and XML Linq : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61607180/parse-big-xml-file-using-xmlreader?force_isolation=true

Comment: Try replacing `ReadOuterXml()` with `ReadSubtree()` as shown in [ReadOuterXml is throwing OutOfMemoryException reading part of large (1 GB) XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46628379/3744182).

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of `while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)`?  Does the XML file contain a line at the beginning that needs to be replaced?

Comment: But beyond that I think we need to see a [mcve] to help you.