# Can JObject lead to Memory Leaks in High Usage Envrionment?

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core, serialization, json.net

I am trying to implement solution in asp.net core 3. I need to make few private properties **REDACTED** for security purposes while logging into file. As JsonDocument is readonly and I cannot use JsonPath as well, I have shifted to NewtonSoft for this purpose and use JObject.Parse. 
My concerns are:

- How much it will affect my performance?
- Will it lead to memory leaks?

Code:

```
var requestTokens = JObject.Parse(requestBodyText); // parse request/response 

foreach (string property in RedactedFields) //for each redacted field in list
{
    JToken token = requestTokens.SelectToken(property); // apply jsonpath
    if (token != null) 
    {
        // jsonpath found
        ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)token).Value = "******REDACTED******";
        requestTokens.SelectToken(property).Replace(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, share the corresponding code and details

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I have updated question with concerned code, please look into it now

Comment: First off, it is very hard to create memory leaks in C# as the garbage collection will take care of that. Unless you yourself keep adding to a static list or do some recursive looping that never stops. And for performance... I'd say run this in a unittest and determine if the performance for both a single run and in bulk is sufficient for your solution. Apart from that it is really hard to help you on this matter.

Comment: @DaveyvanTilburg I have an old solution that has memory leaks and it goes to 100% RAM regardless of RAM size (16 to 72 GB tested). I am revamping the old code and I have had significant achievement in terms of memory but this piece of code gets me confused. System.text.json has JsonDocument and if we do not dispose it, it may lead to memory leaks. Same could be said for JObject or not?

Comment: Ah I see, really high intensity then haha. Well what I know from the garbage collector is that it does not clean objects from the heap (where all reference objects live) unless there is no new memory available. So... lets say, in very high intensity it maxes out, then cleans up as GC.Collect is called, and the circle repeats. We use JObjects for parsing messages in our message channel that processes more than a few million messages a day. No problems there for us atleast.

Comment: `JObject` cannot lead to memory leaks because it holds no unmanaged memory or leases on global memory pool memory.  But any time you use a string longer than 42,500 characters it will end up on the [large object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8953503/3744182) which can fragment memory leading to increased memory use and/or performance degradation over time.  Loading the entire JSON into a single `requestBodyText` is where you are likely to first run into problems.  You should load the JSON via streaming instead.

Comment: Also, load the `JObject` with [`JsonLoadSettings.LineInfoHandling = LineInfoHandling.Ignore`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JsonLoadSettings_LineInfoHandling.htm) to reduce memory overhead.

Comment: Are the properties you need to make private at the root level or nested deep in the JSON hierarchy?

Comment: Thanks @dbc, properties can be nested as well as on root level. Different api has different data and request objects. Can you please refer me to any performance document / forum for JsonLoadSettings.LineInfoHandling = LineInfoHandling.Ignore?.  Also, 42,500 characters seem too much. we usually do not have that much characters in requests. But this method would be used in hot parts of the code such as log middleware and database/file logging in business logic layers.

Comment: @MuqadarAli - I am the source for recommending `LineInfoHandling.Ignore` to reduce memory use (gold badge in [tag:json.net]).  You might also take a look at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm

Comment: Thanks @dbc, this is the only part of my api that uses json.net otherwise I use system.text.json and really needed help in this.

Comment: The only other recommendation I can make from looking at your code is to eliminate `requestBodyText` and deserialize directly to `JObject` or `JObject` from the response stream.  I just found the following article which seems on point: https://johnthiriet.com/efficient-api-calls/

Comment: @dbc, requestBodyText is string read from PipeReader. Will remember your recommendation and apply load testing ;)

Comment: `PipeReader` has an [`AsStream()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipelines.pipereader.asstream?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_IO_Pipelines_PipeReader_AsStream_System_Boolean_) which may help here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212194/discussion-between-muqadar-ali-and-dbc).