# Is there a way to add a number of elements to the array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, for-loop

I'm learning C# and I have created a code to add random numbers to a `List` using a `for` loop.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random numberGen = new Random();
        List<int> randomNum = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            randomNum.Add(numberGen.Next(1, 100));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < randomNum.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(randomNum[i]);
        }       
        Console.ReadKey();       
    }      
}
```

I want to know if there is a way to add random numbers to an **array** with a similar method?

Comment: No it is not. Arrays have a fixed length which cannot be changed. You'll need to copy the Array with `n` more slots and fill those n slots. [Which is what a List does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387286/is-listt-really-an-undercover-array-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of an array is fixed at the time of creation, so you can't *add* to an array; you can, however: create a new array that is bigger, copy the old data, and then append the new value(s) - `Array.Resize` does the first two steps - but: this is pretty expensive, which is why you usually use a `List<T>` or similar for this scenario. A `List<T>` maintains an *oversized* array in the background, so that it only has to *resize and copy* the underlying array *occasionally* (essentially, it doubles the size every time it gets full, so you get something approximating `O(Log2(N))` overhead due to growth).

Answer (score 1):

You could just assign to the relevant index directly, but note you'll have to initialize the array to the required size (as opposed to a `List` that can grow dynamically):

```
int[] randomNum = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < randomNum.Length; i++)
{
    randomNum[i] = numberGen.Next(1, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `List<T>`, thats is the scenario it was precisely designed for. Once you've finished adding elements to it, if you need an array then simply call `ToArray()`:

```
var myList = new List<int>();
//add random number of random numbers
var myArray = myList.ToArray();
```