# Extra List<> object in memory

Tags: c#, list, memory

Consider this simple code:

```
class Program
{
    static List<Data> listData = new List<Data>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Data newData = new Data();
            newData.num1 = i;
            newData.num2 = i * 5;
            listData.Add(newData);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Data
{
    public int num1 { get; set; }
    public int num2 { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason, when profiling memory for this code, it shows that there are **2** Data[] objects in memory (which i assume are listData objects):
[image: dotMemory 4 ss]
Can anyone explain why?

Comment: How did you figure out there are 2 list objects in memory?

Comment: @codequestioneer By using dotMemory 4 and ANTS profilers.

Comment: what is this `ConsoleApplication.Data[]` ? to count how much instance you have use `listData.Count`

Comment: @AsfK listData.Count will give me the number of Data's, not instances of listData's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't have an extra `List<Data>` in memory, you have two `Data[]` arrays.  Which are the underlying storage for the List<> object you created.

List<> starts out with an empty array, the first Add() call creates a Data[] array that can fit 4 elements.  Which runs out on the fifth Add() call, it now creates a Data[] array that's double the size, it can store 8 elements.  Your memory profiler still sees the Data[] array that's garbage, the GC hasn't run yet.

You can use the Capacity property to optimize this.  Lots more details in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2248188/17034).

Comment: Thanks for explaining, but when i force GC - nothing is removed.

Comment: You'll have to ask another question, read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/17034) first.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can count on the garbage collector to do its job... don't worry about it
(I don't have enough reputation to post this as comment)

Comment: Thanks but forcing GC doesn't remove it. And i would like to understand why there are 2 of them.